# How to click to trigger scroll from React Indiana Drag Scroll?

Tags: reactjs

I take a reference from their document and try to use the code.

example link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-initial-scroll-getelement-99o6q?file=/index.js:317-382

example version is `1.7.0`

I install the version is `2.2.0`

```
"react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.2.0",
```

My function component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ScrollContainer from 'react-indiana-drag-scroll';
import { Button, Stack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import styles from './topicCardList.module.scss';
import TopicCard from './TopicCard/TopicCard';

const dummyDataArray = [
    { title: 'One' },
    { title: 'Two' },
    { title: 'Three' },
    { title: 'Four' },
    { title: 'Five' },
    { title: 'Test test test' },
    { title: 'tttttaaaa loojsfk' },
    { title: 'Elevent test' },
    { title: 'fdsagasgj;g' },
    { title: 'dsafsafasdfasdf' },
    { title: 'Onsadfasdfasdfsdfasdfasdfe' },
];

function TopicCardList() {
    const container = useRef<any>(null);

    const scroll = () => {
        if (container.current) {
            console.log('container.current', container.current);
            container.current.getElement().scrollTo(0, Math.random() * 5000);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Stack>
            <Button onClick={() => scroll()}>Click</Button>
            <ScrollContainer ref={container} className={styles.listContainer}>
                <Stack display="grid" gridAutoFlow="column" my="0.5">
                    {dummyDataArray.map((value, index) => (
                        <TopicCard key={index} data={value} index={index} />
                    ))}
                </Stack>
            </ScrollContainer>
        </Stack>
    );
}

export default TopicCardList;
```

1. Try to use `npm install react-indiana-drag-scroll@1.7.0` failed, only 2.2.0 can be installed.
2. console.log the `container.current` can not see any `scrollTo` function.
3. `ref` instead of `innerRef` is still not working.

How to fix the issue ?

Try to fix the code like, but result is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollTo')` console.log the container.current is div list element.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ScrollContainer from 'react-indiana-drag-scroll';
import { Button, Stack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import styles from './topicCardList.module.scss';
import TopicCard from './TopicCard/TopicCard';

const dummyDataArray = [ ...withDummyData ];

function TopicCardList() {
    const container = useRef<any>(null);

    const scroll = () => {
        if (container.current) {
            // print div
            console.log('enter', container.current);
            const containerElement = container.current._container;
            // for Horizontal list
            containerElement.scrollTo({ x: Math.random() * 5000, y: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    };

    return (
        <Stack>
            <Button onClick={() => scroll()}>Click</Button>
            <ScrollContainer innerRef={container} className={styles.listContainer}>
                <Stack display="grid" gridAutoFlow="column" my="0.5">
                    {dummyDataArray.map((value, index) => (
                        <TopicCard key={index} data={value} index={index} />
                    ))}
                </Stack>
            </ScrollContainer>
        </Stack>
    );
}

export default TopicCardList;
```